# Bijection from dihedral group to group of integers

Tags: group-theory, integers

Would it be sufficient to argue that:

(i) Since the only group of order $2n$ for $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ closed under addition;

(ii) And since the greatest order in $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is $2n$, whereas it's $n$ in $D_{2n}$ (dihedral group of order $2n$);

Then it means that there cannot exist a bijection between $D_{2n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$?

Comment: If the two groups have the same order, there is a bijection between the two. But it need not be any sort of (homo/iso)morphism.

Comment: Can there be a homomorphism between two groups of the same order if some elements in one group are of order non-existent in the other group?

Comment: I think not because for $a \in G$ of order $n$, $a^n=1$, but $\phi(a^n  a^n)=\phi(a^n)  \phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n  \phi(a)^n = 1_H = \phi(a)^n \in H$, which implies that homomorphism preserves order. Unless the homomorphism is not surjective.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear so. But a bijective homomorphism does have to preserve order.

Comment: Any surjective homomorphism between groups of equal, finite order is necessarily bijective hence an isomorphim. So yes, your claim holds then, but you do need surjectivity and two finite groups (in which case it's more or less a statement about isomorphisms, again).

Comment: It appears to be that there is no surjective homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and $D_{2n}$, since $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{2n} \to D_{2n}$ doesn't even exist (as far as I can say), and $\psi: D_{2n} \to \mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is not surjective.